# Strange background appearance in tkk.Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I discovered an anomaly in tkinter. I have attached my script below to show the anomaly.

Running this script, I found on my system (Ubuntu 16.04.03) that the background of the `ttk.Frame` appears strange. If I move my mouse pointer in and out of the `ttk.Frame`, the background appearance can change and appear gibberish (e.g. backgrounds from other background windows may appear, strange color patterns may appear,....).

After some investigations, I discovered that by replacing  `background='light purple'` with `background='white'`, the anomaly disappears and the `ttk.Frame` appearance behaves as was defined. That is, the fault was caused by using a background/colorname that tkinter did not recognised.

Questions:

1. Does this anomaly occur in a Mac, Windows or other Linux systems?
2. What are the valid background names that tkinter accepts? I was not
   able to locate it in tkinter's `__init__.py` or `ttk.py`. Where can
   I find them?
3. I think tkinter requires a more robust background name check routine
   to mitigate this anomaly. Who should I attention this to?

**Test Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):

        style=ttk.Style()
        style.configure('App.TFrame', background='light purple')

        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, style='App.TFrame', borderwidth=10,
                           relief='raised', width=200, height=200)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.geometry('300x300')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    app.grid_propagate(0)

    root.mainloop()
```

[image: StrangettkFrameBackground]  [image: StrangettkFrameBackground2]

Comment: I don't see this on OSX. In fact, I've never seen this on any platform.

Comment: @BryanOakley. Thanks. Noted that the code works on OSX. I have tried it on 2 physically different Ubuntu 16.04.3 systems and the anomaly is repeatable. How does tkinter knows which background name is valid? Is this done at tkinter or tcl?

Comment: @BryanOakley I have added another image of the anomaly seen on a physically different Ubuntu 16.04.3  system. Here, the `ttk.Frame` became transparent, revealing the wallpaper of desktop that is behind the tkinter window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Win 10, 3.7.0b1, no background given results in white, a recognized background is what it is, and an unknown background ('light purple' or 'xyz') is black.  As for recognized color names:

The [NMT](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/colors.html) 8.5 reference says "The colors 'white', 'black', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'yellow', and 'magenta' will always be available. Other names may work, depending on your local installation.".

The [tcl/tk 8.6](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/colors.htm) docs list hundreds of color names (but not 'light purple'!) plus some specific to MacOS and Windows.

Comment: One would think tcl would throw out an error msg when an invalid color name is declared. I wonder why they don't?

Comment: @SunBear  I suspect because the validity of a color name depends on the version of the OS in use and perhaps other features of the 'local installation', where as some tk programs are intended to work across platforms.  Any decision like this involves tradeoffs.

Comment: I happened to just answered a related question asked by @Idlehands. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54081432/5722359). From what I learned there, I conclude that the `Frame` widget should raise an Exception for unrecognised colour name. Presently, the `Frame` widget background is yielding multiple snap shots of the `Tk` window window and its content in sometime cascade and random order. I think this occurrence should not be allowed to happen, i.e. a bug fix is needed.