# Why tkinter don't throw/raise an exception?

Tags: python, tkinter

The problem is if you run this code below and resize the window then you will get 
unexpected behavior. Widgets are not rendered like they should and the backgrounds 
have some wierd colors.

I know if you set a  argument then you should 
fill it with a valide value. If you do fill it with an empty string like I did
it don't throw a <_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "">.

My Question is why we
don't get an error? Is that a tkinter bug? Because if you set the bg argument of Canvas
as an empty string you will get an error: unknown color name ""

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Entry, Canvas

class Gui(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.font1 = font=("Segoe UI",18,"bold")
        self.font2 = font=("Segoe UI",28,"bold")
        Frame.__init__(self, self.master, bg="")
        self.grid()  
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):   
        self.frame_container = Frame(self, bg="")       
        self.frame_container.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.button_test_1 = Button(self, text="Test1", bg="yellow")
        self.button_test_1.grid()
        self.can = Canvas(self.frame_container, bg="orchid1")
        self.can.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.entry_test = Entry(self.frame_container)
        self.entry_test.grid(row=0, column=1)            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    bug_gui = Gui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.  The colours you have are recognized that's why it doesn't throw an error.  If you are talking about `bg=""` on the `Frame` it's because if the `bg` is not defined the TCL will use the system default colour.  If you did use an unrecognized colour in `Frame` however, it will throw an error. See the argument for [`background` here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm#Tkinter.Frame.config-method), `bg=""` prevents `Frame` from being updated.

Comment: I encountered this issue before and asked the same question in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020555/strange-background-appearance-in-tkk-frame#comment85047322_49020726).

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking about. When I run your code it seems to work exactly as expected. Also, it's not clear if you're asking about the `unknown color name` error or if you're asking about a problem resizing the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Idlehands Thanks for citing Fredrik Lundh's effbot.org explanation on `background`. I think I finally understand Fredrik Lundh's documentation. Namely,

1. `bg=""` is a valid argument that will prevent the updating of the `Frame` widget's background, and
2. the `background` or `bg` of a `Frame` widget defaults to the application background color.

Hence, when the Tk window is resized, e.g. when the right edge of the Tk window is move to the left to reach the `Canvas` widget's right edge and followed by moving right back to its original position, the following phenomenon happens:

1. Firstly, the `Frame` widget's width reduces in size. When this happens, I suspect the `Tk` widow background colour that filled the `Frame` widget is lost.
2. Secondly, when the `Frame` widget's width next returns to its original size, it's background needs to be updated (i.e. filled) with a defined colour. Because `bg=""` prevents updating, i.e. prevents filling the Frame widget background with a defined background colour, the `Frame` widget's background will default to the "application background colour". Meaning it will be filled with the exact color of the area directly behind the `Frame` widget and the `Tk` window, as if it became 'transparent'.

Answering @Turjak_art question, `tkinter` did not yield an Error or Exception because `bg=""` is a valid argument of the `Frame` widget.

**Edit:**

Image showing Frame background with fast resizing.
[image: bg="" fast resizing]

Image showing Frame background with slow resizing.
[image: bg="" slow resizing]

Comment: I think the effbot documentation is incorrect. `""` is not a valid color, and "prevent the updating of the background" makes no sense. The background isn't updated separately from the rest of the widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have attached an image to show you what `bg=""` gives after  quickly resizing the Tk Window on a Ubuntu 16.04 system. If The resizing is not done quickly I will get vertical edge lines of the `Tk` window or `Frame`. Hence I thought the updating explanation from effbot made sense.

Comment: `bg=""` is only supported for frames, not canvases.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, I agree with you; I noticed this too.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have added the image showing the effects of slow resizing of the `Tk` window right edge on the `Frame` widget with `bg=""` option.

Comment: My apologies for the comments. I was thinking the `bg=""` problem was with the canvas. Yes, I've seen this behavior on frames.

Comment: First of all thank you for taking time to answer my question. It was not clear for you what I meant because of my broken english I know that. To summarize everything: This behavior is not a bug that the frame widgets are drawn in this strange way when defining background as an empty string, right? When defining bg=" " it prevents updates but I thought it just set the color to default, right?

Comment: @Turjak_art "Yes" to your 1st question. For your 2nd question, the default colour is whatever color of the region of the `Frame` widget behind the `Tk` window.

Comment: In the pictures shown above, the `Tk` window was placed in front of this webpage. So the colour of the webpage directly behind the `Frame` widget  is filled into the `Frame` widget's background. The Frame widget contains the `Canvas` and the `Entry` widgets. Their background colours are defined. So these regions of the Frame widget don't show the webpage colours.

Comment: Ok now I'm understanding but it is a strange concept and the documentation is not the best for this color settings.