# TKINTER resizing glitching using Bind

Tags: python, tkinter, resize, tk-toolkit, frames

I am trying to create a button that will resize my tkinter window (the same way that the notches at the edge of a window normally resize). However when I use my resize button the window skips and glitches and does not mirror the actions of the notch at the side of the window. In my example when resizing using the button the text inside the frame glitches around and is not smooth. However when I use the notch on the right side of the window to resize the window, it resizes smoothly without any glitching of the frame.

How can I fix the glitching when using the resize button.

(This is minimal code and there is method to my madness in a much bigger project)!

Thanks a lot. Maks.

```
import tkinter as tk

def resize(self, event=None):

    y=root.winfo_height()

    x1 = root.winfo_pointerx()
    x0 = root.winfo_rootx()

    root.geometry("%sx%s" % (x1-x0,y))

root=tk.Tk()

innerFrame=tk.Frame(root)

h=tk.Text(innerFrame)
h.insert('end','Hello')
h.pack()


g=tk.Button(root,text='Drag to resize')

g.bind('<B1-Motion>',resize)
g.pack()

innerFrame.pack()
```

Comment: I jsut tried this example and for me it works perfectly, all I had to add was `root.mainloop()` at the end. It behaves exactly, as when I use the notch on the side

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, If you resize using the button really fast. For me anyway, the contents of the text widget at some points is not visible. The text widget almost dissapears when using the button however when using the notch at the side however fast I resize the window. The contents of the frame is ALWAYS visible. Is this what you are experiencing?

Comment: No, I do not experience any problems with the button resizing. Never disappears, content always visible. Have you tried it using this minimal example? If not try it, if it works fine the problem is somewhere else in your code ;)

Comment: Weird, I'm running that exact same example now and content is dissapearing. If I call root.update the the start of the resize function then the problem is fixed however I then get RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object. :C

Comment: Tried it with python2 and python3 and no problem with either, sorry, won't be able to help you there...

Comment: Thanks for trying! So frustrating. it's not too much of an issue in the minimal code example but in my project this problem is creating something quite ugly upon resizing ha. https://prnt.sc/pymzym

Comment: I had issues with resizing in my case it was a problem with the color parameter which was very strange. Maybe you have similar problems take a look at this link [Why tkinter don't throw/raise an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079715/why-tkinter-dont-throw-raise-an-exception)